# How can I change what time Deja Dup does its backup?

Tags: deja-dup

I believe it automatically runs at midnight, but I would rather it run during an off-peak internet period to save my quota.

How can I change the time it runs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That feature is [on the wishlist](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/479191), for now you can try setting the schedule to monthly in the preferences and setup your own schedule using crontab and `deja-dup --backup`.

Comment: 12 years later and still not implemented :( Looks like I will need to turn off auto backup and find out how to trigger it manually from a cron job.

Comment: @TimothyC.Quinn  I have switched to borg backup these days. I run it with a cronjob, like you suggest in your answer.

Comment: I used borg for years and it never let me down except when I had to restore, I found it rather slow for large datasets. I'm on the fence about the hash collision failure mode with borg's block de-duplication mechanism. I use ZFS snapshots for my primary backup mechanism and use duplicity (deja) for my onsite backup.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by disabling auto updates in Deja-Dup (Backups) and then running a cron job at a specific time.

To run daily at 2:00 AM add the following to crontab

```
0   2   *   *   *    deja-dup --backup
```